# failed to access mountpoint

Tags: google-drive

I am trying to mount my google drive on Ubuntu 16.04 but I get an error. Any idea ?

$ google-drive-ocamlfuse -o nonempty /home/louisro/Google\ Drive/
    fusermount: failed to access mountpoint /home/louisro/Google Drive: Permission denied

Thanks

**EDIT** the permissions on /home/louisro/Google\ Drive/ are :

```
$ ll -d Google\ Drive/
drwx------ 11 louisro louisro 4,0K août   1  2014 Google Drive/
```

and when tyring to change them I get an error:

```
$ chmod g+r Google\ Drive/
chmod: changing permissions of 'Google Drive/': Input/output error
$ sudo chmod g+r Google\ Drive/
chmod: cannot access 'Google Drive/': Permission denied
$ sudo chown louisro:louisro Google\ Drive/ -R
chown: cannot access 'Google Drive/': Permission denied
```

Comment: what are the permissions on that folder? If it's owned by root, you need to change it to your user. If that's the case, try `sudo chown louisro:louisro "/home/louisro/Google Drive" -R`. Also, It's easier when you don't use empty spaces in folder names or filenames.

Comment: `$ fusermount -u /home/louisro/Google\ Drive/` this solved the issue

Comment: actually no, it didn't solve the issue. any other idea ?

Comment: I still need help on this !